# json code integrated with php

Tags: php, json

I have these following code. could anyone please explain it to me about these code, I did not get all of them.
here is the code

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);enter code here
$params = array();
foreach ($query as $param) {
list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
$params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}
//echo jsonEncode($params);
$categories = implode(", ", $params['categories']);
$types = implode(", ", $params['type']);
```

I am confused about these two variables "$param" & "$params"

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: Well, first the earth cooled. Then [PHP.net](http://php.net) came into the picture and had some great manuals to be read.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well sure there is. You're `J`ay and you're the `SON` of your Dad.

Comment: Stack isn't a "explain this code to me" type of site. It's about dealing with problematic code and this.... looks to be fine to me. The question is too broad.

Comment: @user7381533 i hope your confusion is cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a page is accessed via any query string, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` fetches that query string.

for example, if you call url in your browser like this

http://example.com/index.php?name=msk&job=developer

then `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contain following data

`"name=msk&job=developer"`

and `explode()` used to convert string to array where delimeter is &

`$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);`

now `$query` contain array with following data

```
Array
    (
        [0] => "name=msk"
        [1] => job=developer"
    )
```

.

```
$params = array();  //created to hold $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] array of strings


foreach ($query as $param) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);      
    //above line try to convert "name=msk" into array like this ["name"] => array([0] = msk)
    //list() function is used to assign values to a list of variables in one operation.
    $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}
```

`$params` contain following array data

```
(
    ["name] => Array
        (
            [0] => msk
        )
    [job] => Array
        (
            [0] => developer"
        )
)


echo json_encode($params);
```

`json_encode()` used for converting php array to JSON

```
{"\"name":["msk"],"job":["developer\""]}
```

and come to your doubt

`$param` is just a loop iterator 
`$params` is array used for holding `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` data

Comment: thank you soooooo much, at least somebody is here for helping those are new in programming.... I really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried but it shows me this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."